# MongoDB: Recommended driver for use on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to investigate MongoDB and its use via .NET. I have found the official standard c# driver which according to the docs supports LINQ.

This is something that looks ideal, having little experience with mongo on .net I wondered if anyone is actually use the offical c# driver or some other driver ?

Any help or push in the right direction would be really helpful.

This is the driver I am refering to http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see quite a few people on the user group and here on SO who use the official version, it is quite well maintained by its creators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official C# driver is definitely the way to go for MongoDB in .NET. It is actively supported and maintained by [MongoDB, Inc.](http://www.mongodb.com).

Comment: Thanks for that, I just wanted to ensure it was.